# 13.10 asus K56CB gets very hot and fan is very noisy

Tags: 13.10, fan, fancontrol

Greetings dear Ubuntu users,

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 X64 on my Asus K56CB notebook. And it has not been a good expierence so far.
After one minute, my laptop gets very hot and the fan is going crazy. I think this is because of my laptop having both an Intel GPU and a Nvidia GPU.

I seriously don't know how to fix this problem. I had no problems on Windows 8 with the fan or my laptop getting too hot, but I really don't want to go back to Windows as I like Ubuntu much better.

I really hope someone can help me solve this problem as it is very irritating to work with al that fan noise and a hot keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Nvidia's discrete graphics solution was built with Windows in mind. By default Linux will keep both your GPUs hot all the time. [Bumblebee](http://bumblebee-project.org/) is the Linux answer to Optimus. In Ubuntu 13.10, `sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia` and reboot. webupd8.org have a nice, up-to-date, high-level [guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/8-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu.html).